# how to get QWidgetBackingStore from a QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

I like to know the current dirty region from a QWidget, and QWidgetBackingStore is the only class that I can get it from, as far as I know. But it is kind of hidden class. Is there any way to get QWidgetBackingStore object, or any other way to get dirty region.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you. It contain Collaboration diagram for QWidgetBackingStore:
http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/df/d41/class_q_widget_backing_store.html